# Search all files in a folder

Tags: python, os.system

I want to search "word" in many files in a folder.

I have already :

```
route=os.listdir("/home/new")
for file in route:
```

This does not work :

```
 f = open ('' , 'r')
 for line in f :
```

I tried this :

```
for file in route:
    f = open(file, 'r')
    for line in f:
        if word in line:
            print(file)
            break
```

but I have an error :

```
f=open( file ,'r')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: file.txt
```

When I delete file.txt, next file , I receive the same error.

Comment: Well, that is just the rare first step. Did you do anything on the actual searching the files part already?

Comment: What do you mean by "it does not work"? What is the output?

Comment: The first argument to ``open()`` has to be the file name (i.e. ``file`` in your case), not the empty string ``''`` that you have. After that, go through the file, and search for occurrences of ``"word"`` in ``line`` by using something like ``if "word" in line: # do something``.

Comment: But i would like to do this for all files in folder

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Searching for String and printing the file it is in](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9271353/python-searching-for-string-and-printing-the-file-it-is-in)

Answer (score 2):

How about something along these lines?

```
import os

folderpath = "/.../.../foldertosearch"
word = 'giraffe'

for(path, dirs, files) in os.walk(folderpath, topdown=True):
    for filename in files:
        filepath = os.path.join(path, filename)
        with open(filepath, 'r') as currentfile:
            for line in currentfile:
                if word in line:
                    print(
                        'Found the word in ' + filename + ' in line ' +
                        line
                    )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for file in filelist:    
    f = open(file,"r")
    data = f.read()
    rows = data.split("\n")
    count = 0
    full_data = []
    for row in rows:
        split_row = row.split(",")
        full_data.append(split_row)
    for each in full_data:
        if re.search("word", each) is not None:
            count += 1
```

Something like this, although your question is not at all specific about whether you want to count, return where word was found, change word to something, etc. so feel free to edit it as you see fit

(This code works for .csv as you can probably tell)

Answer (score 0):

[`os.listdir` only returns the file names](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir), not the qualified paths. So to make this work, your `open` needs to be opening the qualified path (constructed with `os.path.join("/home/new", file)`), not just `file`.